# Getting n x n matrix of counts of records based on the categorical values of multiple fields using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table, grid-layout

I want to create simple n x n matrix where n is the every possible unique values of every categorical fields in my data, and the values in the matrix contains a count of records having a pair of two categorical values.

This would be more clearer with the following **sample data** (replication of my actual data)

| user_id | gender | tier | age_group | 20+ such fields |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa | male | tier1 | 15-24 | ... |
| bbbb | male | tier2 | 25-34 | ... |
| cccc | female | tier1 | 15-24 | ... |
| dddd | female | tier3 | 35-44 | ... |
| eeee | other | null | 35-44 | ... |
| ffff | male | tier2 | 45+ | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

**In my actual table there are more than 20 categorical fields (such as Marital_status, Income_band, Education_level, Zone, etc.) and more than 500k records (user_id)**. Each fields can take 2 to 10 fixed categorical values.

**The output** I want is like following - [counts of records which satisfy any two criteria], for example no. of male user living in tier2 cities are 2. so value 2 at the intersection of male x tier2. And so on...

| n x n | male | female | others | tier1 | tier2 | tier3 | null | 15-24 | 25-34 | 35-44 | 45+ | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| male | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| female | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| others | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| tier1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| tier2 | 2 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| tier3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| null | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 15-24 | 1 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 25-34 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 35-44 | 0 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 45+ | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| total | 3 | 2 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

My use case would be getting the overlap between two categorical fields in terms of % of other.

I am not sure how easy or complex it is to get using SQL. I searched for relevant questions but surprisingly I couldn’t find any solution. Hope you can help me on it for SQL. Let me know if any clarification you need for the problem.

Comment: If your gender, tiers and age groups are fixed, then you can do this via a single sql statement by unioning the three pivots together. If the list of values in any of the three columns are dynamic, then you cannot do this in a single sql query.

Comment: Hey, can you elaborate please. I have fixed values of all categorical fields. But keep in mind that there are 20 odd fields, not just gender, tiers and age group.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the sum of duplicate data then u can show accordingly in table.

Here is the query

```
 SELECT
  SUM(gender = 'male') as male,
  SUM(gender = 'female') as female,
  SUM(gender = 'others') as others,
  SUM(tier = 'tier1') as tier1,
  SUM(tier = 'tier2') as tier2,
  SUM(tier = 'tier3') as tier3,
  SUM(tier = 'null') as null,
  SUM(age_group = '15-24') as age_15_24,
  SUM(age_group = '25-34') as age_25_34,
  SUM(age_group = '35-44') as age_35_44,
  SUM(age_group = '45+') as age_45,
FROM users
```

You just have to replace users with your table name.

Comment: How will this give me the overlaps? i.e. How will this answers the questions like - how many female users are from tier1? how many male users are of age 15-24? etc.

Comment: For that You can use && inside SUM()
for example, answer of how many male users are of age 15-24? 
 SUM(gender = 'male' && age_group = '15-24')

It will give the count of data having gender as male and age  between 15-24

Comment: This is a very lengthy and inefficient way. Remember, I have 20 such fields each with 3 to 10 unique categorical values. so it is not practical to use && for each pairs of such categorical values. I want the overlap between each pairs of such categorical values. I just gave example of one such question in earlier comment. Think of such questions for all the fields and all the combinations- like gender='male' && tier='tier1', gender='male', tier='tier3, age_group='15-24' && tier='tier1', etc,etc..

Comment: Also you can't write above code (getting sum) manually for such long list of all categorical values. There are 20 fields and so multiplying with its all possible values. Gender: male/femal/others, tier:tier1/tier2/tier3/null, age_group: 6 possible vales, zone: 5 possible vales, Marital_status: 4 possible values, Premium_user_flag: 3 possible values, user_tenure: 7 possible values...etc.

Better way is to use GROUP BY and get Count of users.

Comment: Can you plz show me your final query u used ?

Comment: I had no clue.That's why I came here for help.It's just that with your logic, I don't think I can get desired output on my large scale problem.

Comment: I think here you have to use  multiple where conditions and multiple counts and multiple group by . so your query still become large. And this Sum() will do all >> count of group with conditions. So I suggested it to you . If you find any better way please let me know. It will be helpful to me. And if u like my answer then plz upvote it.